# How to define the graph obtained by the contraction of a subset of the edges?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph and $Z \subseteq E(G)$. I found definition for contraction of a edge of $G$, denoted by the $G/e$ with $e \in E(G)$ (In the book's Bondy of graph theory). But for the subset of the edges not I found. Where can I found definition of $G/Z$?

Comment: Just contract one edge at a time. Show that it doesn’t matter which order you do it in.

Comment: Look at Diestel's book Graph Theory (Electronic Edition 2000) paragraph 1.7 Contraction and minors.